Mid-1960's large format newsprint sci-fi comic about a crew on a spaceship that landed on an asteroid with infectious fungal plants growing on it
The comic I would like to find out about involved a story about a crew on a space ship that was rectangular in shape, at least four or five times as wide as thick and at least ten times as long as wide; picture something like a short popsicle stick. The crew landed on an asteroid that had some sort of fungal plants growing on it. Some spores got aboard and started to infect the crew.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?
